# show activity only once with Onclick button

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

i'm trying to show an activity only once with Onclick button
firstly i have an activity **useheadphone** contains `button` when user click in this `button` **mainactivity** will start

my useheadphone.java :

```
public class useheadphone extends Activity {
    Button skip;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_useheadphone);
        final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        hide();
        skip = (Button)findViewById(R.id.skip);
        skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)){
                    Intent toMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(toMain);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref.edit();
                    ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
                    ed.commit();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

my **manifest** :

```
<activity
            android:name=".useheadphone"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_useheadphone"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Only if the activity_executed is true will it be set to true. You need to set it to true from when it's false or vice-versa.

Comment: @MikeT thanks so much please give me more informations

Comment: @ S.Queroane:: Based on the comment you left on Doron's answer it appears to me that you are going designing you app backward. If you want useheadphone to only appear once then make MainActivity you launching activity and open useheadphone activity only conditionally, namely when "activity_executed" is true.

Comment: @Barns52 thanks but the answer of **Xenolion** works for me 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46981516/show-activity-only-once-with-onclick-button

Comment: What works isn't always good. Have fun learning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code inside of the onCreate method at the Bottom of `onCreate` method `(dont delete the original I have just copied and paste)`.:

```
if(pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)){
                Intent toMain = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
               startActivity(toMain);
}
```

You should also consider using smaller context here:

**Change this line:**

```
Intent toMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
```

**To:**

```
Intent toMain = new Intent(useheadphone.this, MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: It doesnt go to the next activity?

Comment: yeah but my problem i want when i click to skip button app show the **mainactivity** only once , when i close the app and run it again i want to show the **mainactivit**y ,not the **headphone** activity

Comment: I have edited my answer! The problem should be solved by now! Uninstall the app first

Comment: I am glad your problem was solved! **Happy Coding!**

Answer (score 2):

I think it should probably be something like (you can add an else if you need to):

```
skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)){
                SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref.edit();
                ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
                ed.commit();
                Intent toMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(toMain);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks so much but still doen't work when i close my app and run it again still show me the first activity **useheadphone**

Comment: This answer gives you the correct way to set the `SharedPreferences` in your `onClick` method. (My only suggestion would be to change `getApplicationContext` to `userheadphone.this`).

Answer (score 0):

This code will show main activity only once when user click the button (skip for now) and redirect it to the second activity.

On your **onCreate** method at **Main Activity**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE);
String FirstTimeInstall = sharedPreferences.getString("FirstTimeInstall", "");

    if (FirstTimeInstall.equals("Yes")) {
         startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
    }
```

On your **onClickListener** to your button at **Main Activity**

```
skipBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("FirstTimeInstall", "Yes");
            editor.apply();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
        });
```